# How to convert an image from SVG to PNG in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, svg, intervention, rasterizing

I have searched a lot but did not find a working solution.

I have been trying to convert a QRcode SVG file to PNG format.

The following does return an empty black image but with no content. I would like to convert from the SVG format to PNG format with all the contents:

```
$file = SVG::fromFile(storage_path('app/public/qr_background.svg'));
    $background = $file->getDocument();

    $qrString = QrCode::size('2500')
        ->style('round')
        ->backgroundColor(0,0,0,1)
        ->generate( 
            env('FARMCODE_BASE_URL') 
            ? env('FARMCODE_BASE_URL') . $product->id 
            : route('product-landingpage', ['product' => $product])
        );
    $qr = SVG::fromString($qrString)->getDocument();
    $qr->getChild(1)->setAttribute('transform', "translate(450,450) scale(44)");
    $background->addChild($qr);

    $name = 'abc.png';
    // Make image with Laravel Invervention package 
    $image = Image::make($file->toRasterImage(2000,2000))->encode('png');
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'image/png',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename='. $name,
    ];
    return response()->stream(function() use ($image) {
        echo $image;
    }, 200, $headers);
```

> I am using `meyfa/php-svg` `simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode` and `intervention/image`

Comment: Have you tried simply doing what the `php-svg` README show? https://github.com/meyfa/php-svg#rasterizing. I'm not sure you even need Intervention here, might be complicating things.

Comment: I don't suppose you bothered to read [the documentation](https://www.simplesoftware.io/#/docs/simple-qrcode) for your package? It has a built-in method for selecting the output format, PNG is one of the options.

Comment: @miken32 I have already used the methods from the documentation but did not work